# Determine if a % Change occurred

Tags: time-series, group-differences, structural-change

I'm trying to figure out if a change to a website that occurred on a specific date increased page views on that site by 5%. I have page view data for a month before the change and several weeks after. The page views fluctuate on a daily basis by +-5%, so how can I determine if a change in page views was caused by something specific or just part of the normal fluctuation?

Comment: Do you have auxiliary data about the event. You could test for Granger causality if you did.

Comment: Is the change a spike (a one time thing) or a level shift (so the mean is now at a different level)?

Comment: This change occured and stay, so i guess a different level. But i'm seeing daily fluctuations, so I don't know how to tell if the change had any effect.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to use the t-test as that ignores trend.  You need to use time series methods specifically "intervention analysis".  You build a causal variables(dummy variable) that has zeroes before and one when you made the change and on out.  For example 0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1.

Post your DAILY data to dropbox.com so we can take a look or here.  You need to account for daily fluctations as well using 6 day of the week dummies.

Comment: Provided there is a trend.  The original post didn't mention anything about trends in the data.   A dummy variable is a great idea though.

Comment: Are you saying that there are no trends in data??

Comment: I'm not saying that data doesn't have trends, my point was more that not all data has trends. As the question didn't mention trends my suggestion for a t-test was reasonable.

Comment: The t-test assumes there is no trend.  There is no need to live with that assumption when you can test that in the analysis.

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard t-test where you have group1 (pre event) and group2 (post event).  You can calculate the means of each group and do a test to see if they are the same or not.  If they are statistically different then you can infer what %age change you have had.

The changepoint tag is not warranted on this post as the change is at a known time point.  If you wanted to test if a change has occurred or not (without specifying the time point) then you could use changepoint analysis to do this.